Alignment after opening parenthesis of function call
I'm using clang-format for my C++ codebase
Here's the current set-up:
# .clang-format
BasedOnStyle: Chromium
IndentWidth: 4
---
Language: Cpp
ColumnLimit: 79
AccessModifierOffset: -4
SortIncludes: true

Currently when breaking a function call over multiple lines it aligns the arguments after the break with the opening parenthesis:
# some_file.cpp
some_really_long_function_call_that_overflows_the_length_of_the_line(bar,
                                                                     baz,
                                                                     bat);

But I'd like it to break the line and then indent with two "tabs" (spaces, 4 per tab) on the new line, ie:
# some_file.cpp
some_really_long_function_call_that_overflows_the_length_of_the_line(bar,
        baz,
        bat);


See: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html I think you want BAS_DontAlign
